# Symfony Doctrine Persist Many To One

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm having an issue persisting Entities associations with Doctrine in Symfony. Straight to the point:

The idea is to have a `Dossier` Entity, which can only have one `Offres` Entity, whereas an `Offre` Entity can have multiples `Dossier`.

Ideally, I wish to access this relation from both sides (bilateral).

I followed Doctrine's documentation and ended up with the following YAML configurations :

```
Dossier:
type: entity
    table: dossier
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        *a bunch of fields*
    manyToOne:
        offre:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Offres
            inversedBy: dossiers
            cascade: ["persist"]
            joinColumn:
                name: dossier_offre
                nullable: false
```

And for `Offres`:

```
Offres:
    type: entity
    table: offres
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        *a bunch of fields*
    oneToMany:
        dossiers:
            targetEntity: AppBundle\Entity\Dossier
            mappedBy: offre
            cascade: ['persist']
```

My controller inserts the data as such (considering $offre is a valid `Offre` entity and all methods used exist) :

```
$dossier = new Dossier();
$dossier->setOffre($offre);
$offre->addDossier($dossier);
$em->persist($dossier);
$em->persist($offre);
$em->flush();
```

If I try to return
    `$dossier->getOffre();`
just after persisting and flushing, the data is right and the offer is diplayed.

But once I leave the page, the data is lost.

I also have this problem on other types of relations (many-to-many) for contacts. There can be multiple `Contacts` involved in different `Dossiers`.

I hope I am clear enough so that anyone can help, in advance, thanks!

Comment: A question: did you look in your database if the data is persisted ? And a comment : if you do `$dossier->setOffre($offre)`, you don't need to do also `$offre->addDossier($dossier)`. I don't think it's the cause of your problem, but can you try to suppress this line ?

Comment: Actually I tried without this line and then added it just in case (but I set cascade option so I knew it was not the problem). The data is not in database, since no columns exist for those properties, how are those data supposed to be stored ? As a join table or as a column in one of the tables ? Thanks!

Comment: It is supposed to be stored in a "dossier_offre" column in your "dossier" table, given your Doctrine config. This is the way Doctrine stores ManyToOne relations. 
If you say the column does not exists, maybe you haven't created it yet ? Run : `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql`, you will see the diff between your actual database and the doctrine mappings ; then `php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` to update your db.

Comment: Actually after checking the column exists (and in PHPMyAdmin if I click the id of the offer it takes me to the right entity on the other table), but when I retrieve the "Dossier" entity in another controller, the method `$dossier->getOffre()` returns an entity with all fields empty except for the id field. Problem seems to be the entity `__isInitialized__` field is false

Comment: Can you show the code of your entities and of your controller, then ?

Comment: `$repository_dossier = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Dossier'); $dossier = $repository_dossier->findOneById($job); $offre = $dossier->getOffre();` Then I return this data in an array, but the offre index is still `__isInitialized__ = false`

Comment: This portion of code seems correct, but can you put all of your both entities and controllers code, because it's difficult to help without it  ?

Comment: Controller code can be found here http://pastebin.com/L2wLFpwK entity `Dossier` here http://pastebin.com/Vsny7V8U entity `Offre` here http://pastebin.com/ZXDvQ5gp thanks again for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved my own question.

Turns out Symfony/Doctrine only initialize entities when you need them. Dumping the data will not load the entity, but trying to access the property in twig will load the selected entity.

This is very efficient (doesn't load all unnecessary fields).

So I'm a little bit ashamed but here is what I used to try (in twig template with above controller):
    `{{dump()}}`

That would not initialize the `Offre`entity, but this does return the name :
    `{{dump(dossier.offre.name)}}`

Thanks for all the help!